# Powder In A Pile

Tags: particles, add-on

I'm trying to achieve a result similar to this one.

[image]

I'm just trying to find a method my actual goal is to make a path of powder.
I tried using a particle system then converting it to a mesh but the particles just went through each other so I used molecular addon but all the particles seemed to explode.

(edited)this is an example of what I meant by a path/trail of powder
[image]

but this is a photo taken from afar so its details do not appear entirely. I want to achieve the second photo with the same amount of detail as the first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use Geometry Nodes:

[image]

[image]

You could then duplicate the object, duplicate the node tree, and modify it slightly to add another layer:

[image]

[image]

- Duplicate the object to create a 3rd layer.
- Apply the Geometry Nodes modifier of the 2nd layer, add rigid body physics: passive, mesh shape, full friction (could increase it over 1 manually, but I tried with 1).
- Modify the 3rd layer increasing min Poisson distance, so the particles don't overlap. Apply this modifier as well.
- Move the 3rd layer a little up, maybe rotate around Z 180° if they look to similar to underlying particles, in such case remember to apply rotation.
- Set Physics: active, convex hull shape, full friction (1.0), mass 100 kg.
- <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> Separate By Loose Parts.
- <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> "Set Origin to Center of Mass (Volume)".
- Add a plane, move it a little up (I was sloppy with removing the bottom of the cone), add passive physics, also full friction.

That's about it. Could repeat or tune this process but you get the idea.

[image]

### Path

For a short path, just bevel a curve and use that as the geometry to spawn particles. For a longer path you probably want to resign from a simulation altogether - it was just a lazy way to get some particles outside of the geometry. Instead you can just spawn some particles on a plane, using "Geometry Proximity" to the curve to control the density of points.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could I possibly ask for a blend file please, it's all for a personal project I'm not gonna sell it or smth plus i mentioned earlier that my original goal is to achieve a trail of powder.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed

Comment: you helped me so much this far but if I could ask you one last thing, I need to change the shape of the path and I'm a beginner when it comes to geo nodes so is there a way to do so using the curve pen for example? plus my pc lags a bit when I use the file so I couldn't really keep messing around with the settings till i get a better result

Comment: @JoxXx reduce the number of instances (e.g. by increasing the minimum distance in the poisson distribution), don't use sliders while doing that, just input new values with keyboard. As for a curve, you can import a curve just like I import a profile (cross section) for the path, then you can use it to replace the spiral. You will need to readjust the caps because they are positioned manually.

Comment: Will do, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

Your actual goal is a path of powder? I will assume that is a typo and you want a pile of powder. You could use particle system with fluid physics, OR use rigid bodies. The picture you show here is a pile of *crystals*, rather than *powder*.

1. Powder can be achieved by creating a convincing mesh, subdividing it and using large scaled noise to achieve the shadows between particles. This one is not very convincing but it can be very low poly.
2. Crystals can be achieved by using rigid bodies, with random transforms and simulating the gravity effects. Use a cone as a passive rigid body to save memory.

[image]

[image][image]

[Blend file. Bake before running sim](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16jQk-7VOi5vj7wrhyAsYf4GObwB_IWEV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Those cuboid particles are sweet!

Comment: That's great thank you so much but I actually meant a path of powder like a trail